# Why does keras.Model subclass behave differently to the sequential API?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

I have implemented WGAN based on this [blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-code-a-wasserstein-generative-adversarial-network-wgan-from-scratch/). I tried to implement `define_critic()` as a subclass of keras.Model with the goal of having the same result.

```py
class CNNBlock(layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, channels, kernel_size=(4, 4)):
        super(CNNBlock, self).__init__()

        w_init = initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02)
        const = ClipConstraint(0.01)

        self.conv = layers.Conv2D(channels, kernel_size, strides=(2, 2), padding="same",
                                  kernel_initializer=w_init, kernel_constraint=const)
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.relu = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
        x = self.conv(input_tensor)
        x = self.bn(x)
        return self.relu(x)


class CriticModel(Model):

    def __init__(self, channel):
        super(CriticModel, self).__init__()
        self.cnn1 = CNNBlock(channel[0])
        self.cnn2 = CNNBlock(channel[1])

    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False, mask=None):
        x = self.cnn1(input_tensor, training=training)
        x = self.cnn2(x, training=training)
        x = layers.Flatten()(x)
        x = layers.Dense(1)(x)
        return x

    def get_config(self):
        super(CriticModel, self).get_config()
```

However, when I run the code, I get an error on the call `c_model.train_on_batch(X_real, y_real)`.

**Error**

```
ValueError: tf.function-decorated function tried to create variables on non-first call.
```

I don't understand why my change leads to this error.

The entire code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/molitoris/2206931e0f87c8442358073acb4a37bb)

Answer (score 0):

I create two new objects in `call()`: `layers.Flatten` and `layers.Dense`. When I create the objects in the constructor, the model works as expected.

````
class CriticModel(Model):

    def __init__(self, channel):
        super(CriticModel, self).__init__()
        self.cnn1 = CNNBlock(channel[0])
        self.cnn2 = CNNBlock(channel[1])
        self.flat = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense = layers.Dense(1)


    def call(self, input_tensor, training=False, mask=None):
        x = self.cnn1(input_tensor, training=training)
        x = self.cnn2(x, training=training)
        # x = layers.Flatten()(x) <-- This creates a new obj at eacht forward call
        # x = layers.Dense(1)(x)  <-- This creates a new obj at eacht forward call
        x = self.flat(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        return x

    def get_config(self):
        super(CriticModel, self).get_config()
```
````